# How to validate XSL file?

Tags: validation, xslt

could anyone help me with XSL file validation? I don't want to validate it for start/closed tags but for "inside atributes".
For examle:
My XSL file contains line `<td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>`
I need check this one for syntax errors like `<td><xsl:vae-of select="year"/></td>`.

Is there any way how to do this with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: I think the use of an element that is not defined in its namespace will be caught by XML validation. So maybe this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334119/check-for-xml-errors-using-javascript

Comment: It could be, but just partly...
I would show message what is wrong. In this case something like wrong parameter "vae-of". I know it exist, but i can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT processor checks the stylesheet code so in Mozilla browsers you could pass a DOM document with your stylesheet code to the `importStylesheet` method of an `XSLTProcessor` object e.g.

```
var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
var sheet = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">',
    '<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:vae-of select="year"/></xsl:template>',
    '</xsl:stylesheet>'
    ].join('\n'), 'application/xml');
try {
    proc.importStylesheet(sheet);
}
catch(e) {
    // handle error here e.g.
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

outputs "Component returned failure code: 0x80600001 [nsIXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet]".

But be aware that an XSLT 1.0 processor is supposed to process stylesheet code with a version greater than 1.0 in [forwards compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards) mode and that way if you wanted to validate user input code as XSLT 1.0 you would need to make sure that it has `version="1.0"` to catch any errors against the version 1.0 of the XSLT language.

And of course that error message is not very helpful to identify what's wrong in the code.

Comment: That's it! Thanks :)
I'll try to find some info about line of error, but this is what I looked for!